# how to see what was updated in last update

Tags: updates, 14.04, history

Recently I downloaded automatic updates which Ubuntu offered me automatically (Classic "Confirm, confirm, OK... done" without actually reading what is being installed)

I feel like that as result of that [I cannot read properly questions from UX site in Firefox](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/user-experience-site-unreadable)

How do I check what was updated in the last update I confirmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see what has been upgraded or installed, through an automated process or by your own decision.